# How to plot a resampled pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe, just `date` column and `amount` column:

```
    local_date  amount
48  2020-01-01   30.00
464 2020-01-01    1.49
465 2020-01-01   22.45
469 2020-01-01    7.49
472 2020-01-01   19.17
473 2020-01-01   49.37
475 2020-01-01    7.72
481 2020-01-01   59.98
482 2020-01-01    8.20
483 2020-01-01   14.24
```

Dtypes:

```
local_date    datetime64[ns]
amount               float64
```

I want to resample it so I get the weekly sum of `amount`, then plot it.

The resampling works:

```
df.set_index('local_date')['amount'].resample('W').sum()

local_date
2020-01-05    339198.67
2020-01-12    570769.94
2020-01-19    556042.39
2020-01-26    564230.50
2020-02-02    569204.69
2020-02-09    606505.21
2020-02-16    620612.11
2020-02-23    618156.03
2020-03-01    645825.50
2020-03-08    688377.73
2020-03-15    892803.67
2020-03-22    783538.04
2020-03-29    856011.93
2020-04-05    243519.71
Freq: W-SUN, Name: amount, dtype: float64
```

But when I add `.plot()` to this I get an error:

```
df.set_index('local_date')['amount'].resample('W').sum().plot()


TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'
```

I am sure I have plotted with this method many times before. If the plot argument does not accept a period, does it have to be converted to a string?

Comment: I can't reproduce using `Python 3.7.3` with `pandas 1.0.3`

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way.

Data

Coerce Date to datetime

```
df['local_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['local_date'])
```

Groupby date and calculate sum of amount per date

```
df.groupby(df.index.date)['amount'].sum().reset_index().plot()
```

Comment: I was trying to get the weekly sum.

Comment: df.groupby(df.index.week)['amount'].sum().reset_index().plot()?